# php D3linq MYSQL How to handle not set fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the D3Linq lib for PHP to run Sql type queries on an array, I have a array which contains values as per below but with a number of other data, this table is generated by a script which in turn is fed from an API. In my data sometimes values are  not set and I get round this by giving them an invalid value in the case below X

```
Row   HTBO    DBO   ATBO
1     1.65    3       8
2     X       X       X
3     5       4       3
```

The problem is if I write the following Code

`select * from table where HTBO>2`  Row 2 is returned and I don't want it to be

If I set Row 2 to be '' and run `select * from table where HTBO<2`  again Row 2 is returned

How can I exclude any rows where the returned value is not a numeric value, Im aware I can add htbo <>'' or htbo <>'X' but my queries can be quite complex such as

`SELECT * FROM matchdata WHERE timep>'15' AND timep<'19' AND totalg='0' AND (totalshotot>='2' OR (eap1>='40' AND (o05fhg>'59' OR a15>'69')))`

Comment: The problem is with implicit string to number conversion (which would be easy to accomplish) that it converts strings to 0 numeric value, but you said you did not want that. To be honest, such problems should be handled on the input side (do not let the API insert such values into the table). Otherwise, you have to explicitly filter the unwanted values per field.

Comment: Thanks, Shadow, I have control over the API and the table, the question is what value to add to the table when the variable is not set, I need something that will not match when I use < > or =, I have tried leaving the field blank, setting it to NULL or adding a character for the reasons you rightly outline these all fail

Comment: I would use null, since any comparison with null value returns null, not true or false.